# Graphicsmagick how to forcely covert 32bit image to 24bit bitmap

Tags: command-line, bitmap, graphicsmagick

I would like to force all the input image to be converted into 24bit bmp format. what parameters in gm command line I should add?

`gm convert input.png -resize 1920x1080 out.bmp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i figured out, just let you guys know

```
gm convert input.png -resize 1920x1080 +matte out.bmp
```